# url rewrite parsing a custom url parameter not working

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

For SEO purposes I want to add a few specific urls to act as aliases to the archive page for a custom post type archive page that I have.

Now the custom post type archive page optionally accepts GET parameters which I then do various things with if they are parsed.

Taking the example below from my functions.php file, the add_rewrite_rule() does work in so far as going to /test/url/ on my site does take me to the archive page for the custom post archive page.  So the basic catch is definitely working as I don't get a 404 page.

However the get parameter (param1) doesn't appear to have made the rewrite.  It's as if it wasn't defined.

```
function rewrite_test() {

   add_rewrite_rule('^test/url/?', 'index.php?post_type=custom&param1=value']), 'top');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_test');
```

So what is wrong with this, how can I get the custom url parameters I want parsed via the rewrite rule?

Comment: Assuming you're getting this param with `get_query_var('param1')`, you must add `param1` to the [query variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)

Comment: Ah fantastic @SamuelElh !  Do you want to write an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to append the new variable (`param1`) to the public query variables:

```
add_filter("query_vars", function( $vars ){
    $vars[] = 'param1';
    return $vars;
});
```

Now you'll be able to get the value of this param with [`get_query_var( 'param1' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/).

Comment: One sticking point; I've copied my code to the live server and now it doesn't work there.   I've tried adding/removing proceeding and trailing slashes but no change.  Any ideas?